# App crashing when appending a new line using nline.setText("\n")

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to append new line in the text view of my app:

I used this code

```
textView.setText("part 1");
TextView nline = null;
nline.setText(" \n");
textView.setText("part 2");
```

My app is crashing as I go to the page which implements this.

Comment: @flx i guess now I have my doubt clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
App crashing when appending a new line
```

Because  your `nline is null` and you are getting `NullPointerException`

```
TextView nline = null;// Check here nline is null
nline.setText(" \n"); // and your using null nline here which is causing NPE
```

Make sure what do you want to do ! i am assuming you need new line b/w Part 1 and Part 2

if so then you can simply use

```
textView.setText("part 1 \n part 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

`nline` is null. You can't assign anything into the `nline`.

```
TextView nline = new TextView();
    nline.setText(" \n");
```

instead of

```
TextView nline = null;
    nline.setText(" \n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're setting nline to be null, then you're calling setText to something that is null which throws a nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 0):

**Please don't set null to textview.**

```
textView.setText("part 1 \n part 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 TextView nline = null;  
 nline.setText(" \n");
```

Of course you are getting a `NullPointerException`.

I guess what you are trying to do the this:

```
textView.setText("part 1" + "\n" + "part2");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
textView.setText("part 1\n part2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set next line by this way :

```
   TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textid);
   textView.setText("part 1 \n part 2");
```